# CSS - My images are overlapping my text on a smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlapping

On my website the images overlap my main content text when on a smaller screen size. At home it was perfectly fine because my screen is much bigger but now I'm at college and it looks horrible.

Is there anything I could do to fix this?

```
#content {  
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 955px; 
}
```

**Here is a picture of the problem:**
http://i776.photobucket.com/albums/yy41/tom14431996/problem-1_zpsa410ef94.png

As you can see the image overlaps the text.

**This is an example code of how my first image is added:**

```
#imageholder1 {
float: left;
left: 2%;
position: fixed;
top: 11%;
border: double;
border-color: #333;
```

}

**And this is my text code:**

```
#content {
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 955px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Just remove `position: fixed;`

Comment: 2014 copyright? oops....

Comment: `float` and `position` don't mix.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't position your images with `position: fixed;` for your current situation.  `position: fixed;` is for keep an element **fixed** on the screen so that it never moves.  When you view your images on a smaller screen, the text must move somewhere, so it overlaps the fixed images.

Try setting a width to your text's class/id of something like `50%` so it adapts to your screen width.  I can help further if I can see some more html/css.

Try `position: relative;` on your images as well.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` is putting the images over the text. Keep the images inline if you want to text to show around them.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're using `position: fixed;` - when you do that, the element takes up no space in the layout, and goes on top of statically positioned elements (the default). Your `float: left;` is doing nothing here, since you can't have an element that floats and is fixed position. You can either fix this by using margins and/or padding to ensure a minimum size, so that the fixed elements are always over top of the margins/padding. Or you can actually use float, which will make the content flow around the images.

Comment: So should I just remove the position: fixed; on all the images and then position them using margins/padding?

Comment: No, if you're using the margins/padding it would be on the content, to account for the fixed position of the images. But using float instead is definitely a nicer solution. In that case you'll probably want to use margin as well, but for different reasons.